# PostGIS: ST_Covers fails for extremum point location

Tags: postgis

I am using PostGis to save geographical data and then use `ST_Covers()` function to find if a point or location lies with in a geography or not.

I can save a location with extremum values like:

```
-90,180;90,180;90,-180;-90,-180;-90,180
```

These values will tend to cover whole globe (lies along side the poles). I can save such a location and can retrieve it with no worries. However, when I call `ST_Covers()` on such locations, to find if a location lies within such location, the function fails and gives parse error.

I am using Postgis 1.5.3, upgraded to 2.0.2 but with little luck.

Can anybody please help me if something like this is possible. and how can I call `ST_Covers()` on such a location without any error.

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS geography will not correctly interpret any edge greater than or equal to 180 degrees. Re-formulate your box with shorter edges and you should get what you desire.

Comment: Thats what i thought originally, But i want something more elegant, like Geometrical implementation of ST_Covers function did remove the orignal error but it is too slow when running on large data.